# Using GNU Parallel With Split

Tags: bash, split, gnu-parallel

I'm loading a pretty gigantic file to a postgresql database. To do this I first use `split` in the file to get smaller files (30Gb each) and then I load each smaller file to the database using `GNU Parallel` and `psql copy`.

The problem is that it takes about 7 hours to split the file, and then it starts to load a file per core. What I need is a way to tell `split` to print the file name to std output each time it finishes writing a file so I can pipe it to `Parallel` and it starts loading the files at the time `split` finish writing it. Something like this:

```
split -l 50000000 2011.psv carga/2011_ | parallel ./carga_postgres.sh {}
```

I have read the `split` man pages and I can't find anything. Is there a way to do this with `split` or any other tool?

Comment: split --verbose maybe?

Comment: @KevinDTimm The verbose option prints when it starts to create the file, not when it finishes

Comment: And so, when it creates file X2, start parsing file X1 :)

Comment: @KevinDTimm But I want to avoid the need to have an extra script to do that.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could let parallel do the splitting:

```
<2011.psv parallel --pipe -N 50000000 ./carga_postgres.sh
```

Note, that the manpage recommends using `--block` over `-N`, this will still split the input at record separators, `\n` by default, e.g.:

```
<2011.psv parallel --pipe --block 250M ./carga_postgres.sh
```

#### Testing `--pipe` and `-N`

Here's a test that splits a sequence of 100 numbers into 5 files:

```
seq 100 | parallel --pipe -N23 'cat > /tmp/parallel_test_{#}'
```

Check result:

```
wc -l /tmp/parallel_test_[1-5]
```

Output:

```
 23 /tmp/parallel_test_1
 23 /tmp/parallel_test_2
 23 /tmp/parallel_test_3
 23 /tmp/parallel_test_4
  8 /tmp/parallel_test_5
100 total
```

Comment: The `--pipe -N 50000000` options of parallel will send the 50000000 lines to `carga_postgres.sh` stdin?

Comment: @Topo: Yes that's correct. I've edited the answer to illustrate how `--pipe` and `-N` work.

Comment: Since you input is gigantic, you may want to look at --joblog --resume  --resume-failed (requires version 20130222).

Comment: @Thor I really liked your answer, but when I ran it, zsh gives me an error, something like: `zsh: 4 expected number` and I just can figure out what the problem is.

Comment: @Topo: I also use `zsh` but am unable to reproduce this error. Does the test example work? What versions of `parallel` and `zsh` are you using? Does it help if you run this under `zsh -f`?

Comment: @Thor The test example did work, about the other info, I'll have to wait til tomorrow to post.

Comment: Parallel is exactly what I needed, the machine I'm working on doesn't support --filter in split, and parallel execution is great too!

Answer (score 3):

If you use [`GNU split`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html), you can do this with the `--filter` option

> ‘--filter=command’
>       With this option, rather than simply writing to each output file, write through a pipe to the specified shell command for each output file. command should use the $FILE environment variable, which is set to a different output file name for each invocation of the command.

You can create a shell script, which creates a file and start carga_postgres.sh at the end in the background

```
#! /bin/sh

cat >$FILE
./carga_postgres.sh $FILE &
```

and use that script as the filter

```
split -l 50000000 --filter=./filter.sh 2011.psv
```

Comment: What `cat` is doing in you example, is writing each line that `split` sends through stdin to the file `$FILE` and then pass `$FILE` file name to carga_postgres?

Comment: @Topo Correct, split sends the lines to the filter's stdin. `$FILE` is the name split has chosen. You are free to use another unique name, of course.

Comment: I've been doing some little (just execute a `head -1` in every file) tests and when I add the `&` at the end of the filter flag, the files generated for the `split` are empty and the command `head` doesn`t display anything... but if I execute the `split` without the `&` the split-generated files are normal and `head` prints to the screen ... Is this the correct behaviour or I am doing a terrible interpretation?

Comment: @Topo I just tested this and stdin is indeed redirected from `/dev/null`, if you run the filter with `&`. But if you run the filter without, split will wait until the filter exits, before starting the next filter. So it seems, you must use the script version in order to run carga_postgres.sh in parallel. I updated my answer accordingly.