# How use GNU parallel and GNU SQL with \copy in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, parallel-processing, sqlbulkcopy

I want to do a bulk load to a PostgreSQL database, there are several files and are pretty big. I just read in [Using GNU Parallel With split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144655/using-gnu-parallel-with-split) about the `GNU Parallel` and `GNU SQL`, and It looks fantastic, Could some one help me with an example of using `GNU Parallel`, `GNU SQL` and `\copy` or `COPY` for doing a bulk load to PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use [`pg_bulkload`](http://pgbulkload.projects.pgfoundry.org/) instead. It does that, and more, for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but, I know that `pg_bulkload` do that, but I am asking for an example of `GNU Parallel` + `GNU Sql` + `copy` in PostgreSQL...

Comment: @nanounanue Ah, ok; many people asking bulk-loading questions are unaware of it and tend to specify other candidate tools. As you didn't mention having looked at alternatives it wasn't clear from your question that this wasn't such a case. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Both GNU parallel and pg_bulkload are cool, but not available in most default installations. I think this task can be achieved by using '&' (background sub-shell) and 'wait' in a shell script, which invokes multi \COPY operations simultaneously. Here is an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

PG_USER_NAME=bizusr
PG_DB_NAME=bizdb
BCP_DIR=/data/biz/bcp/input

do_bcp()
{
    TABLE_NAME=$1
    echo "`date` $$ copy $TABLE_NAME begin"
    psql -q -U $PG_USER_NAME -d $PG_DB_NAME << EOF
-- SET DATESTYLE TO 'ISO,YMD'; -- you may need this when dealing with timestamps
\COPY $TABLE_NAME FROM '${BCP_DIR}/${TABLE_NAME}.bcp' WITH (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER '|');
EOF
    echo "`date` $$ copy $TABLE_NAME done"
}

echo "`date` $$ parallel copy started"
for BCP_FILE in `ls ${BCP_DIR}/*.bcp`; do
    TABLE_NAME=`echo $BCP_FILE|awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'|sed -e s/\.bcp$//`
    do_bcp $TABLE_NAME &
done

wait
echo "`date` $$ parallel copy finished"
```